# Please assist me in calculating the MonthlyBillDate based on the Excel data provided

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know the Monthly bill date based on the policy Entry, Policy Effective date. and I have taken Monthly Bill dates from DB for couple of policies as a reference.!!
Please help out and also let me know the solution/formulae to retrive monthly date.

I have tried different scenarios as I mentioned the attached data. I want  Monthlybill date for L11 policy.

Here the below formulae for various dates

InstallmentDate= PolicyEntryDate+1

InvoiceDuedate=Max(InstallBilldate+20,PolicyEntryDate)

RemindarNotice=InvoiceDuedate+5

Pastdue=RemindarNotice-4

Please let me the formulae to get the **MonthlyBillDate**??

[image]

[image: screenshot: results after formulae]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I checked(PolicyNo:L1 to L10)to see if there was any connection to other dates (PEff,PEntry,Install,Pastdue,Remind)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean: `=EDATE([policyeffectivedate],1)+11` only 31/12/2021 gives (exactly) 1 month difference. Could that be a mistake in your data?

Comment: This formulae is working as expected. Thanks you so much.!! @P.b

Comment: @Ben If you work with dates at all, you will definitely want to be familiar with EDATE() and EOMONTH().  They are *extremely* useful.

Comment: I was testing the above formulae for different policies, it's working well for many of the scenario's but some of the monthly date's(Marked in Red)  are different https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVbgq.png . Any idea? @P.b

Comment: I am new to Excel and we don't mostly work on excel but yeah once in a while.!! @MaxR Thanks for your suggestion. Could you also look at my recent comment. any suggestions or help is really helpful to me.!!

Comment: @Ben, I already commented the difference on 31/12/2021. Could that not be an error in the data? Also, where's those dates coming from. Can't you ask the logic there? It seems to be a manual thing with my suggestion as a base or that date + 42.